# Configure log4j to send its logs to Splunk?

Tags: log4j, splunk

I need to send my log4j logs to Splunk. I found several solutions:

1. To use REST API (e.g. `curl -k -u admin:changeme -d "name=/tmp/myfile.log" -d "sourcetype=syslog" https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/data/inputs/monitor`)
2. Install Splunk Universal Forwarder
3. Use log4j appender
   such as:

   #### Syslog appender

   log4j.appender.splunk=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
   log4j.appender.splunk.SyslogHost=localhost:8089
   log4j.appender.splunk.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.splunk.facility=LOCAL2
   log4j.appender.splunk.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %t: %m%n

but it seems to me that 3rd solution wouldn't work if splunk server and log are located on separate machines.

2nd solution requires to install additional software

Can anyone propose any other solution?

PS I tried to use opensource java libs. But it didn't give a result.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this great project from one of our community developers @damiendallimore - https://github.com/damiendallimore/SplunkJavaLogging

It provides a number of options for logging directly to Splunk.

It also uses the Splunk Java SDK:  http://dev.splunk.com/view/java-sdk/SP-CAAAECN